# product of the reaction iodine with alcohol

Tags: organic-chemistry

I have a multiple choice question. 
The product from the reaction of iodine monochloride, ICl, with pent-1-ene is:

A CH3CH2CHICHClCH3
B CH3CH2CH2CHICH2Cl
C CH3CH2CH2CHClCH2I
D CH3CH2CHClCHICH3

the correct answer is C but I really don´t get it at all. Does this have to do with electrophile and nucleophiles?

Answer (score 1):

The answer will be (C) option.

As we know Cl is more electronegative than I hence ICl will break as I+, Cl-.

Now the double bond will break and positive charge will appear on the second carbon ( this is due to higher inductive effect of 2 alkyl groups), whereas the negative charge will appear on the first carbon. You may think of rearrangement but that will not happen here because the degree of the carbocation will not change (rearrangement occurs only in case of increase in degree of carbocation).

Now join the positive and negative charges and you will get your answer.

HOPE THIS HELPS.(IF I AM WRONG PLEASE DO INFORM ME. BUT I AM 99% SURE OF THIS ANSWER)